How to make an entity move in a RealityView so that collisions can be detected
I'm trying to detect when two entities collide. The following code shows a very basic set-up. How do I get the upperSphere to move? If I set its physicsBody.mode to .dynamic it moves due to gravity (and the collision is reported), but when in kinematic mode it doesn't respond to the impulse:
struct CollisionView: View {

    @State var subscriptions: [EventSubscription] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let upperSphere = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.04))
            let lowerSphere = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.04))
            
            upperSphere.position = [0, 2, -2]
            upperSphere.physicsBody = .init()
            upperSphere.physicsBody?.mode = .kinematic
            upperSphere.physicsMotion = PhysicsMotionComponent()
            upperSphere.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            
            lowerSphere.position = [0, 1, -2]
            lowerSphere.physicsBody = .init()
            lowerSphere.physicsBody?.mode = .static
            lowerSphere.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            
            let sub = content.subscribe(to: CollisionEvents.Began.self, on: nil) { _ in print("Collision!") }
            subscriptions.append(sub)
            
            content.add(upperSphere)
            content.add(lowerSphere)
            
            Task {
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
                print("Impulse applied")
                upperSphere.applyLinearImpulse([0, -1, 0], relativeTo: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

Furthermore, if I set up the physicsMotion with a velocity: upperSphere.physicsMotion?.linearVelocity = [0,-1,0]
It moves down, but no collision is registered.

You just need to switch ball's physics body mode from .static to .dynamic. Kinematic mode is used only when the user needs to manually control a physics body movement.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct CollisionView : View {
    @State var subscriptions: [EventSubscription] = []
    let upperBall = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.12))
    let lowerBall = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.12))
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            upperBall.position = [0,2,-2]
            upperBall.physicsBody = .init()
            upperBall.physicsBody?.mode = .static
            upperBall.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            
            lowerBall.position = [0,1,-2]
            lowerBall.physicsBody = .init()
            lowerBall.physicsBody?.mode = .static
            lowerBall.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)
            rvc.add(upperBall)
            rvc.add(lowerBall)
            
            let sub = rvc.subscribe(to: CollisionEvents.Began.self) { _ in
                print("Collision detected")
            }
            subscriptions.append(sub)
            
            Task {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
                upperBall.physicsBody?.mode = .dynamic
            }
        }
    }
}


@main struct ColliderApp : App {
    var body: some Scene {
        ImmersiveSpace() {
            CollisionView()
        }
    }
}


Thank you. One small point to add - I need to set isAffectedByGravity to false on the physicsBody, and then my impulse command will get it moving.

Philip, I totally agree, but gravity does its job anyway.
